# Extend node.js REPL completer

Tags: node.js, read-eval-print-loop

I implement my custom REPL, I see that we can specify completer function. But I don't wont to replace the existing completer I want to extend prev one. For instance, I would like to add additional autocompletion (function, let, const), but leave all perv autocompletion such as defined vars

```
const customRepl = repl.start({
  prompt: '> ',
  preview: true,
  useColors: true,
  terminal: true,
  completer: extendedCompleter
});
```